# Determine the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \frac{1}{(4n)^2-1}-\frac{1}{(4n+2)^2+1}\right)$ using the Fourier series of $|\cos x|$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-series

I need to determine the sum $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \left( \frac{1}{(4n)^2-1}-\frac{1}{(4n+2)^2+1}\right)$$ using the Fourier series of $\lvert \cos x\rvert$ on the interval $ [-\pi,\pi]$.

I have already calculated Fourier series and I get this:
$$\lvert \cos x\rvert= {\frac2\pi}+\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac4\pi}\frac{\cos(n\frac\pi2)}{1-n^2}\cos(nx)$$

I do not know how to manipulate the Fourier series to get that specific sum.
I tried this but did not get me anywhere. 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac4\pi}\frac{{\frac12}\cos(n\frac\pi2-nx)-{\frac12}\cos(n\frac\pi2+nx)}{1-n^2}$$
$$-\sum_{n=2}^\infty{\frac4\pi}\frac{\cos(n\frac\pi2-nx)}{2n^2-2}-\frac{\cos(n\frac\pi2+nx)}{2n^2-2}$$

Comment: $\cos(n \frac{\pi}{2}) = 1 \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: @Max This is by factor 4 far from truth.

Comment: Sorry, lack of coffee. Was meant to be $=0$.

Comment: Its not 0, it can be 0, -1 or 1 depending on n

Comment: Oh dammit, i'm getting coffee now! Sorry for the nonsense.

Comment: No problem haha

Comment: Are you sure that this is written correctly? The answer I get is $\frac7{10}-\frac\pi8\tanh\left(\frac\pi4\right)$, and $\tanh$ comes in because $(4n+2)^2+1=0$ has no real roots.

Answer (score 3):

The sum of the first term is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(4n)^2-1}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{4n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left[1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{4n-1}\right]\\
&=\frac12+\frac18\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n-\frac14}\\
&=\frac12-\frac\pi8\cot\left(\frac\pi4\right)\\[6pt]
&=\frac12-\frac\pi8\tag1
\end{align}
$$
The sum of the second term is
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(4n+2)^2+1}
&=\frac i2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{i-(4n+2)}+\frac1{i+(4n+2)}\right)\\
&=\frac i2\left[\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{i+(4n+2)}-\frac1{i+2}-\frac1{i-2}\right]\\
&=\frac i8\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{n+\frac{2+i}4}-\frac15\\
&=\frac{\pi i}8\cot\left(\pi\frac{2+i}4\right)-\frac15\\[3pt]
&=\frac\pi8\tanh\left(\frac\pi4\right)-\frac15\tag2
\end{align}
$$
where we have used $(7)$ from [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) (which uses complex analysis) or Theorem $2$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3140959) (which uses Fourier Series).

Subtracting $(2)$ from $(1)$ yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{(4n)^2-1}-\frac1{(4n+2)^2+1}\right)=\frac7{10}-\frac\pi8-\frac\pi8\tanh\left(\frac\pi4\right)\tag3
$$

Comment: Mathematica agrees with this answer.

Comment: Thank you sir, I have checked your answer, it is correct, just in the first sum is (4n)^2 and not 4n^2. Also my answer is also correct, i have checked it with wolfram mathematica also on yt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bG6bpYlQx2s

Comment: @Davor: you mean that the first sum should be $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{16n^2-1}$? Are you going to alter the question, or ask another with the correct sum?

Comment: Yes, i have corrected the equation, but it does not matter that much, i was more interested how to do it. We did not learn that approach with complex analysis, only usinf fourier transform

Comment: How did you get that the sum at the first line gives 1 for non integers? @robjohn

Comment: @LSS: I am not sure what you mean. Are you asking about this answer?

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(4n)^2-1}
&=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{4n+1}\right)\\
&=\frac12\left[1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{4n-1}\right]\\
\end{align}
$$

@robjohn i didn't understand how do you went from the first part, to the second :)

Comment: @LSS: $$ \begin{align} \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{4n-1}-\frac1{4n+1}\right) &=\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^m\left(\frac1{4n-1}+\frac1{-4n-1}\right)\\ &=\overbrace{\quad\ 1\quad\ \vphantom{\sum_m^m}}^{\substack{\text{this cancels}\\\text{the $n=0$ term}}}+\lim_{m\to\infty}\overbrace{\sum_{n=-m}^m\frac1{4n-1}}^{\substack{\text{this sum includes}\\\text{$n=0$, which is not}\\\text{in the sum above}}}\\ &=1+\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\frac1{4n-1} \end{align} $$